# Android How to change layout_below to TextView programmatically

Tags: android

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/aaa"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/xxx" />
```

How to remove or add layout_below in the TextView, programmatically?

Comment: please tell me about more things..? if you need answer you need to explain the things effectively..?

Comment: Put your cursor at the end of the line and hit backspace until the line is deleted. Thank me later.

Comment: When I change my orientation I want to remove or add layout_below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see 2 ways.

**First way**, you need to create new layout with same name but in folder `layout-land`, copy all content here and remove `layout_below` rule.
In this case, you just declare another layout, which not contains `layout_below` rule

See this screenshot:

[image: 2 layout for different orientation]

This means, that you defined different layouts for different orientation.
in `layout/my_layout.xml`:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/aaa"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/xxx" />
```

in `layout-land/my_layout.xml`:

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/aaa"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

For more information, see [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html) link:

> Table 2. Configuration qualifier names, row with name "Screen orientation"

**Second way**, in your java code(onCreate() method for example):

```
if(Activity.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE){
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) yourView.getLayoutParams();
    lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, 0);
    yourView.setLayoutParams(lp);
}
```

**EDITED**

Comment: I did not understand the last line `yourView.setLayoutParams(p);` what is `p` and where is the `aaa` and `xxx`?

Comment: @HasanAYousef, not `p`, but `lp`. Regarding `xxx` - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_below